# マクロでヘッダーを割り振る方法

Tags: emeditor

```
a■あああ■いい■ううう■え■おおおお……
```

というデータをマクロで

```
aあああ
aいい
aううう
aえ
aおおおお……
```

に変換したいのですが、区切りの「■」の数は不定で、「a」や「あああ」などの長さも不定です。

下記のような形でいちおう得られるのですが、同じ命令を十分な数だけコピペしています。

```
document.selection.Replace("^([^■]+)■([^■]+)(■.+)$","\\1\\2\\n\\1\\3", eeFindReplaceRegExp | eeReplaceAll )
document.selection.Replace("^([^■]+)■([^■]+)(■.+)$","\\1\\2\\n\\1\\3", eeFindReplaceRegExp | eeReplaceAll )
document.selection.Replace("^([^■]+)■([^■]+)(■.+)$","\\1\\2\\n\\1\\3", eeFindReplaceRegExp | eeReplaceAll )
document.selection.Replace("^([^■]+)■([^■]+)(■.+)$","\\1\\2\\n\\1\\3", eeFindReplaceRegExp | eeReplaceAll )
document.selection.Replace("^([^■]+)■([^■]+)(■.+)$","\\1\\2\\n\\1\\3", eeFindReplaceRegExp | eeReplaceAll )
document.selection.Replace("^([^■]+)■([^■]+)$","\\1\\2", eeFindReplaceRegExp | eeReplaceAll )
```

このような繰り返しを避けるにはどのようにすればよいでしょうか。
初心者のため、if文などをどのように書けばいいか分かりません。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 変換のルールを明記してください。

Comment: 行頭から最初の“■”までの部分を取り出し、その行の各“■”の直後にそれを入れ、“■”を改行文字に替える、ということを意図しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

次のようにマクロを書いてください。

```
document.selection.StartOfDocument(false);  // 文頭に移動
document.selection.Find("([^■]+)(?=■)", eeFindNext | eeFindReplaceCase | eeFindReplaceRegExp, 0);
str = document.selection.Text;  // 最初の文字列 "a" を取得して str に代入
document.selection.Replace("■", "\\n" + str, eeFindReplaceCase | eeFindReplaceEscSeq | eeReplaceAll, 0);
document.selection.StartOfDocument(false);  // 以下、最初の行を削除
document.selection.SelectLine();
document.selection.Delete(1);
```

Comment: おかげさまでうまく行きました。コメント付きでお教えくださりありがとうございます。

Comment: たびたびすみません。
行が複数ある場合、

a■ああ■いい
b■うう■ええ
c■おお■かか

↓

aああ
aいい
b
aうう
aええ
c
aおお
aかか

となってしまいます。

aああ
aいい
b
bうう
bええ
c
cおお
cかか

とするにはどうすればよいでしょうか。

Comment: 異なる質問なので別のスレッドにしていただけると幸いです。